# Android: Finding ListView's item rendered height

Tags: android, listview

Is there any way of finding the height of a ListView's item currently being shown in the list without setting it yourself in the layout xml files?

I've tried

```
View listItem = listAdapter.getView(currentIndex, null, listView);
listItem.measure(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int itemHeight = listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
```

and while it worked initially, it decided to throw a Null Pointer Exception during the measure() call after starting a new emulator session.

What I'm attempting to do is have an item in a short list (only 2 or 3 full items are visible) be centered when selected by the program.

Comment: Add the error in your question. I think `listAdapter.getView(currentIndex, null, listView)` returns null. As listItem is null you get NullPointerException when you call `listItem.measure()`.

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter?
Maybe it's better do this measure from the custom adapter, since the height is calculated just after the view is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
public static int getItemViewHeight(Context context, Adapter adapter, int index) {
    FrameLayout fakeParent = new FrameLayout(context);
    View view = adapter.getView(index, null, fakeParent);
    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    return view.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```